# How to use QTP to test the application which operates in citrix of Remote Machine?

Tags: c#, python, ruby

When i tried recording using QTP, every thing goes well till the application sign in. i.e it gets upto the user Id and password entry, But QTP fails to recognise afterthat. Is there any way to handle this?

Application is to be invoked using Citirx, in VPN.

Answer (score 0):

QTP performs GUI recognition and interaction through Windows Handle. 
So it has to be running ***under*** Citrix (i.e. installed on the same virtual machine as your Application Under Test).

If you have the above, make sure Screen Resolution, Windows Theme, Font size, and other global GUI settings are the same.